# R - Trying to model cumulative probability over time with confidence interval

Tags: r, probability

This is a combination of statistics and R newbie question.

Right now I am working with a set of estimates of the probability of observing a certain event (with binary outcome: either it happens or it doesn't) on a given day. These estimates come with a standard deviation. For the sake of this example, let's say that's:

`p = 0.31` (probability of event)

`p_SD = 0.007` (standard deviation of that probability)

When dealing with discrete days and a certain probability (i.e. without `p_SD`), I know that if I ask the question "What's the probability of the event happening at least once over three days?", the answer is:

`1 - (1 - p)^d` where `d = 3` (i.e. three days)

However, the number of days is a continuous variable in my case, and my probability of event (`p`) is uncertain with `p_SD`. How do I model (in R) the curve that represents the increasing probability of the event happening as a function of time, while taking into account `p_SD`?

Ultimately, I hope to:

(1) Plot that curve ("days" on x-axis, and "probability of the event occuring at least once" on y-axis) with shaded confidence interval derived from `p_SD`.

(2) Be able to answer questions like "If I want to be 95% sure that the event will happen at least once, how many days do I have to wait?"

Since the event is a binary variable, I am guessing some use of `glm` in R to do a logistic regression, but I can't quite put my finger on how. Is that the correct direction or is it something else? How do I implement (1) and (2)?

Comment: A standard deviation is not sufficient. You need a distribution assumption for p.

Comment: `d <- seq(1:100)` and `p_event <- 1 - (1 - p)^d` and you can do `plot(p_event)`, but as Roland said, you need a distribution assumption, is it maybe Biomial? Poisson?

Comment: Thank you @Roland & @RLave. By distribution assumption do you mean the distribution of `p`? I calculated `p_SD` from a sample of 200 `p`s, so were you referring to the distribution of those 200 `p`s or is it something else?

Comment: You could plot it with ggplot. Here with glm, but you could look at your plot with "Loess" too. Does that help you?                                                                     plot<-ggplot(df, aes(days, as.numeric(outcome)) +
  stat_smooth(method="glm",method.args = list(family = "binomial"), formula=y~x,
              alpha=0.2, size=2) +
  geom_point(position=position_jitter(height=0.03, width=0)) +
  xlab("Days") + ylab("Probability of outcome")

Comment: @LarsG Thanks for your suggestion. But in your `df`, is it comprised of two columns with `days` as number of days until the event outcome, and `outcome` as whether the event occurred as 1 and 0? If so, should I generate that data frame with my `p`? If so, is there a way to account for `p_SD`?

Comment: you need something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution, more in general https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Discrete_probability_distribution

Comment: How did you calculate p_sd? You assumed a distribution?

Comment: @LarsG: I had a list of 200 `p`s, and I simply used `sd(p)` to get `p_SD`.